# Understanding Monotonic Imbalance Bounding (MIB) vs Equal Percent Bias Reducing (EPBR) classes of matching methodologies

Tags: matching

There are 2 major classes of matching methods, according to a content analysis by King and Nielsen (2018). They are:

1. **Equal Percent Bias Reducing (EPBR)**
2. **Monotonic Imbalance Bounding (MIB)**

**Mahalanobis Distance Matching** (MDM) is an example of EPBR and **Coarsened Exact Matching** (CEM) is an example of MIB. I have a rough idea of how those 2 classes might be defined based on their names and the example algorithms.

However, I would like a clear and compact definition of each, with a comparison of their advantages and disadvantages. An example of when you might prefer one class over the other would be helpful.

When I try to find this from online resources I mostly find only journal articles that are more narrowly focused on other topics rather than any educational comparison. One exception is *Definition 3* of this [Harvard thesis](http://abel.harvard.edu/theses/senior/neel/neel.pdf) for EPBR.